# I am getting a "No such signal error" when using QSignalMapper under Linux

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals, qsignalmapper

```
No such signal QSignalMapper::mappedString(QString)` is the exact error
```

I am working on an effect engine plugin for OpenRGB but I have run into some issues with Linux

```
QCheckBox* SelectedBox = new QCheckBox();
QSignalMapper* DeviceSelectionMapper = new QSignalMapper(SelectedBox);
DeviceSelectionMapper->setMapping(SelectedBox, "DeviceName");

connect(SelectedBox,SIGNAL(clicked()),DeviceSelectionMapper,SLOT(map()));
connect(DeviceSelectionMapper,SIGNAL(mappedString(QString)),this,SLOT( DeviceSelectionChanged(QString)));
```

DeviceSelectionChanged is under `private slots:`

Also to be clear this does work under Windows (I am trying to do this on WSL by the way,)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Which Qt version do you use? `mappedString` is new in Qt 5.15, which is pretty recent. Previous versions provided several overloads of the signal named `mapped` instead.

Comment: I think you are right about my Qt version
I am apparently 5.12 so I guess that makes sense if it is new to 5.15